# Weird issue on Drupal 7 site

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7

For the first time in my 3 Years of development I deals with a problem that I can't figure out how and why happens.

It is on http://idealpvc.ba

If you scroll down to the bottom of every page you will se:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache Server at www.idealpvc.ba Port 80
```

I tried to find issue in Network Tab but I can't see any of request that have `error 404`.

Also, I'm looking to find any by this values, html tags ( http://prntscr.com/8eojsm ) but there is nothing.

Is it possible that site is hacked and something is injected ?

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Check out is some file is missing (deleted recently) and you are trying to get it.?f I.e. that bembasa.mp3 is not found...

Answer (score 0):

When I load the url, I get a 404 error for **bembasa.mp3** I think  the reason for this is this line
`<source src="http://idealpvc.ba/bembasa.mp3" type="audio/ogg">`

Regarding the 404 error, you may have to check the access log, to know what exactly is the url this is being requested which is throwing the 404 exception.

Comment: I remove all things related to bembasa.mp3. We don't have that error in network tab, but still at the bottom of page there is the same issue "Not found..bla". 
I'm totally without ideas..

Answer (score 0):

1 - You have to check index in tpl to prevent errors message , on your site http://www.idealpvc.ba/i have message after relaoding :

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in include() (line 41 of
> /home/idealpvc/public_html/sites/all/themes/Porto/templates/page/page.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in include() (line 41 of
> /home/idealpvc/public_html/sites/all/themes/Porto/templates/page/page.tpl.php).

2 - Have you XHR request or file_get_contents in any own modules ?

3 - Check page.tpl or html.tpl if everything is fine

4 - Use drush to see logs in same time loading page with this command line :
drush wd-show --tail

5 - Check apache log with comme line :
tail -f /my/path/to/apache/log.log